# Apply pattern recognition to user authentication for malicious attempts

Tags: authentication, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

To strengthen the authentication mechanism (web), I would like to log a user fingerprint for every attempt and apply pattern recognition to distinguish malicious attempts. For example if the user always logs in from European computers and there is an attempt made from China, the user is blocked until the user confirms (via email, for example) to allow logins from China.

I have a very, very small knowledge of pattern recognition from a university course. However, I cannot recall enough to start developing this service. What I know is that you should look at these various features:

1. Browser agent string, resulting in:

   - Operating system
   - Browser vendor
2. IP address, resulting in:

   - Location
3. Time stamp of login
4. Number of (failed) attempts (within session, or total)

You search for patterns and any extraordinary attempt is marked because it does not follow the average pattern. You probably will apply a threshold, so if a user logs in at night or has a new PC, it still works.

There are also a few requirements: first, the check of an attempt must be made real-time. You cannot block access after 2 minutes if the credentials were OK but you found out later on the attempt could have been malicious. Furthermore, all our apps are written in PHP, but PHP is probably too slow for this. I prefer to use Python then, but subsequently there is also a binding to Python required.

So the question is: where to start? What is the best approach to accomplish this? I can log all data in a key storage like Redis or document based like Mongo. How would I design a service which allows to validate a new attempt with certain features against a bulk of known other attempts? And return whether the attempt matches the average within a timely fashion, say 250ms.

Comment: First of all, you already seem to know the patterns you want to block. Second, the features you mention are quite basic and limited in the possible hypotheses they can express; how can they yield anything surprising instead of stuff you could have thought of yourself? Third, you don't seem to have a dataset of malicious and nonmalicious login attempts to train on. Altogether I'm not sure if machine learning is really what you are looking for.

Comment: I agree with all the points Junuxx made except "you don't seem to have a dataset of malicious and nonmalicious login attempts to train on". You will only need labelled data if you are going down the supervised classification route.

Comment: just an idea: convert that 4 points (user agent, ip...) to a number, so that every login has a number that represents the "kind of login" we have. Store that numbers for each user and use them to see how different a new login is.

Comment: @Junuxx + mbatchkarov You triggered a clue of supervised vs unsupervised for me. I think there is no requirement for "machine learning" than but rather unsupervised pattern recognition. Machine learning could result in features interesting to look for, but to keep it simple, I just can select those features of my own. Am I right in this?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called anomaly detection- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) is a good place to start. As a first stab, you might want to try clustering:

- you will need a data set. The good news is clustering is unsupervised, so you will not have to mark up a ton of login attempts as regular or malicious.
- For a given user, keep a history of their past N logins (big brother warning!) and features of those logins. The features you have listed are a good start, but you can think of more.
- apply a clustering algorithm to estimate what the average login is like. For every new attempt you can calculate the distance from the average and decide if it look malicious or not.

As a side not, you can go a long way without learning. My intuition is the location of the login and the number of failed attempts will get you most of the way there. A simple if-else might be good enough.

Comment: This sounds already great, I will have a look at how to cluster multiple features and calculate a distance to the profile. The theory gets back now, I only have to figure out how to deal with this in practice.